# KVM, CentOS and CVE-2018-3639

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, vulnerabilities

Today news have reached me about specter (https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2018-3639). I'm running CentOS and kvm infrastructure. Fix is critical and planning to deploy it in few days. I have running kvm VMs and in link is mentioned that VM complete shutdown and start is required. My question is that if I migrate VM from one KVM host (not updated) to another (updated) will it be enough? VMs are critical and complete shutdown and start circle is not a bets option.

Do you know something about that? Do you know how to test it if this enough? Please, share your knowledge

Comment: Before Migrating a vm, you need to shut down the vm right?

Comment: @ShahriarShojib No, I would like to do live migration to another host to keep VMs running in all upgrading process

Answer (score 0):

Migrating the VM is not enough.
You have to restart the VM on the updated host, otherwise the VM will not be protected.

Comment: How about host? At this time I'm not concentrating to VMs security

Comment: If the VM is not protected it can be abused to attack the host.